# Presenting a non-arc ViewController from within an arc ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

-- UPDATED NAMES AND ADDED BACKTRACE AFTER INTEGRATION INTO MASTER APP --

I have a simple iOS application which consists of two controllers:

1. BXDemoViewController which **does not utilize ARC**.
2. TestViewController which **utilizes ARC**.

I am trying to present the BXDemoViewController from within the TestViewController using the following code
which is invoked upon the touch of a UIButton:

```
-(IBAction) invokeScanner: (id)sender {
    BXDemoViewController * scannerController = [[BXDemoViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:scannerController animates:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the controller gets invoked correctly and works well, however when dismissViewControllerAnimated:
gets called I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Converting the presenting controller (TestViewController) into
non-ARC code gets rid of the problem which suggests to me that it has something to do with the way i am
allocating and using the BXDemoViewController but i would like to keep the TestViewController in ARC.

I am relatively new to iOS development and my limited knowledge tells me that i am suppose to somehow
bridge the BXDemoViewController since it is called within an ARC controlled source but i am not sure how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Backtrace output:**

```
thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x32d5f5b0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8002b192)
frame #0: 0x32d5f5b0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
frame #1: 0x31df0b5e CoreFoundation`+[__NSArrayI __new:::] + 58
frame #2: 0x31df03b6 CoreFoundation`-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 270
frame #3: 0x39682fe6 UIKit`-[UIView dealloc] + 98
frame #4: 0x32d61488 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 168
frame #5: 0x31de9440 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
frame #6: 0x31e79f40 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1296
frame #7: 0x31decebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
frame #8: 0x31decd48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
frame #9: 0x39bea2ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
frame #10: 0x396a82f8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
frame #11: 0x00002296 BXDemo`main + 90 at main.m:15

thread #3: tid = 0x2903, 0x31084648 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
frame #0: 0x31084648 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
frame #1: 0x344a54f0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 796
frame #2: 0x34497df8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 36

thread #5: tid = 0x2b03, 0x31083eb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
frame #0: 0x31083eb4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
frame #1: 0x3108404c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 40
frame #2: 0x31e7b044 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 128
frame #3: 0x31e79da2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 882
frame #4: 0x31decebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
frame #5: 0x31decd48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
frame #6: 0x36148a44 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 444
frame #7: 0x344df310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308
frame #8: 0x344df1d8 libsystem_c.dylib`thread_start + 8

thread #6: tid = 0x2427, 0x3109408c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
frame #0: 0x3109408c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
frame #1: 0x344d7d2e libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 646
frame #2: 0x344e1f18 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_wait + 40
frame #3: 0x381f39a8 CoreMedia`FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 260
frame #4: 0x3499035a MediaToolbox`fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 26
frame #5: 0x3821198a CoreMedia`figThreadMain + 194
frame #6: 0x344df310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308
frame #7: 0x344df1d8 libsystem_c.dylib`thread_start + 8

thread #9: tid = 0x2e03, 0x000aa468 BXDemo`BitmapIsPixelOn(tagBITMAP const&, long, long) + 60
frame #0: 0x000aa468 BXDemo`BitmapIsPixelOn(tagBITMAP const&, long, long) + 60
frame #1: 0x000a9df2 BXDemo`PointMoveTillOffNoisy(tagPOINT&, Direction, tagBITMAP&, long, long) + 290
frame #2: 0x0007f966 BXDemo`ReaderDataMatrix::FindBarcodeBoundaries(tagBITMAP&, tagPOINT, tagPOINT, _BCDM*, signed char) + 3278
frame #3: 0x0007df6c BXDemo`ReaderDataMatrix::DMBarcodeRecognition(BarcodeReaderInfo&, tagBITMAP&) + 324
frame #4: 0x0007de08 BXDemo`ReaderDataMatrix::Recognize(BarcodeReaderInfo&, tagBITMAP&, BarcodeResultList&) + 236
frame #5: 0x000abba2 BXDemo`BarcodeReader::PerformRecognition(tagBITMAP&) + 686
frame #6: 0x000ab858 BXDemo`BarcodeReader::AnalyzeBarcode(ImageBase*, long, long*) + 112
frame #7: 0x000ab186 BXDemo`BXiOSAPI::recognize(void const*, int, int, long, long, bool, IOSResult&) + 398
frame #8: 0x000af860 BXDemo`-[BXRuntime RecognizeImage:width:height:stride:result:] + 244 at BXRuntime.mm:630
frame #9: 0x000ae2ee BXDemo`-[BXRuntime recognizeData:] + 234 at BXRuntime.mm:215
frame #10: 0x000b11cc BXDemo`-[BXThreadQueue dispatchThread:] + 296 at BXThreadQueue.mm:133
frame #11: 0x33a9067c Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 972
frame #12: 0x344df310 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 308
frame #13: 0x344df1d8 libsystem_c.dylib`thread_start + 8

thread #10: tid = 0x2f03, 0x344d489c libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread
frame #0: 0x344d489c libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread
```

Comment: Issue is with the `dealloc` method of your `BSViewController`. Please put a break point there and check. Probably you are releasing some uninitialized objects there. Nothing related with ARC. If you are using non-arc, did you released that object after presenting it ?

Comment: can you show the console output

Comment: I'd suggest (a) running your code through the static analyzer (shift-command-B or choosing "Analyze" from the "Product" menu; and (b) turning on [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) for all exception types. But I don't think the problem rests in the code of the question, but elsewhere (e.g. something wrong in `BSViewController`'s allocation that only manifests itself when `BSViewController` is deallocated after it's dismissed). Without seeing more code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hey everyone. Thanks for helping. Midhun MP: I attempted to put a breakpoint at the dealloc of BXDemoViewController before, it went through all of the releases and dealloc of super fine. I also just attempted to release the controller after presenting without utilising ARC. It appears to result in the same problem. Backtrace has been added for the output received from the exception breakpoint. Also, just to clarify it for later, using zombie is not an option because the controller uses a camera preview.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the non arc viewcontroller to arc controller by using the below method

Targets->Compiler Sources->Double click the .m file of non ARC Viewcontroller added and give the flag as -fno-objc-arc. Now it will work fine.

Comment: Hey Uma. Thanks for trying to help out. However, i have tried to do the conversion before without luck. Once again, EXEC_BAD_ACCESS was received upon dismissing the BS controller.